# Repo from heroku to github

Tags: django, heroku, github

I'm kind of new in this of heroku and github, but what I want to do is put a Django application in heroku to my github account. How can I do that from console or something?

Answer (score 2):

You have a local git repository of your code that you pushed to heroku. Now you just got to http://github.com (create an account if you haven't yet) and a repository for your project. You will then get the instructions to push your existing code to the newly created repo.

Comment: And how can I do to push commits in my heroku and github repos at the same time?

Comment: let's say you have your app already pushed to heroku and github repo created. `cd your-app` and `git remote add github git@github.com:username/repo.git` then after commiting changes you push them to github with `git push github master` and deploy to heroku with `git push heroku master`